# how to use JHTML::_('behavior.modal') in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am creating a component,

```
controllers
    theatercontroller
    facilitycontroller
Models
    theater
    facility
view
    theater
    facility
```

What I want is I want to add a new facility from the theater view by clicking a button and opening a modal window. I have tried but didn't work. I studied some components but it is difficult for someone like me to understand it. Please I need a simple example and a explanation to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function to get a modal button

```
static public function getModalButtonObject($name,$text,$link,$width=750,$height=480)
{
    JHTML::_('behavior.modal', "a.{$name}");  // load the modal behavior for the name u given
        $buttonMap = new JObject();   // create an Jobject which will contain some data, it is similar like stdClass object
        $buttonMap->set('modal', true);
        $buttonMap->set('text', $text );
        $buttonMap->set('name', 'image');
        $buttonMap->set('modalname', $name);
        $buttonMap->set('options', "{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: ".$width.", y: ".$height."}}");
        $buttonMap->set('link', $link);
        return $buttonMap;
}
```

And HTML can be written as

```
<a id="<?php echo $buttonMap->modalname; ?>" class="<?php echo $buttonMap->modalname; ?>" title="<?php echo $buttonMap->text; ?>" href="<?php echo $buttonMap->link; ?>" rel="<?php echo $buttonMap->options; ?>"><?php echo $buttonMap->text; ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for you code. I am new to this so can you please explain what is happening there and how to use it.

Comment: There is nothing special in it. I have just loaded a modal behavior, for the button and created a JObject which can be used in HTML.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't have to be anywhere near that complicated. Many templates turn the modal behavior on already, but if they don't all you need to do is add this to the head -

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); ?>
```

Then add this to any links you want to open in a modal window -

```
class="modal"
```

Everything else is optional.

Comment: I have used it to your way It loads fine but when I saved it it will load the view with menus and toolbar. I don't know how to prevent it.

Comment: What are you loading in the modal window and what are you saving?

Comment: You need to add &tmpl=component to the url you are loading in the modal window