# pop up in joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I have been doing popup functionality in Joomla CMS. I have used the functionality used in html5 using JQuery mobile in Joomla for popup.I am able not getting any popup in Joomla 1.5.Can any one help. I have tried many plugins.Can any opne help me

Comment: by clicking image i need it to be displayed in popup along with its description.

Comment: yes, try jquery [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

Comment: i didnot need gallery but i need separate popup

Comment: what you have done so far. You have to read the logic of these colorbox/pop up plugin and customize as per your requirement.

Comment: i also need to play video on popup

Comment: I am new to this. Please help me. Is there any documentation how to use it.I mean color box

Comment: there are plenty of jquery plugins that play video/image etc, also ther are well documented with examples

Comment: can you send me some links related to this

Comment: @paripurna:did you try this-http://stackoverflow.com/a/8622928/902161

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin you can play video and image in popup
[click here](http://demo.rockettheme.com/extensions/?extension=rokbox)

Comment: i am using joomla 1.5 version

Comment: this is for both 1.5 and 2.5 check this link http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbox

Comment: WHERE TO DOWNLOAD THIS PLUGIN

Comment: you can download it from here http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-downloads/club/1005-rokbox

Comment: i am not able to get popup using this plugin

Comment: have you used correct syntax in article editor eg :{rokbox title=|Audi RS8 :: Sample Caption for RS8 Image| size=|561 350|}images/demo/rokbox/rs8.jpg{/rokbox}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18450/discussion-between-deepak-and-paripurna)

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla 1.5 users, add the following to the very top of your template:

To open a modal window, use a link formatted like Your text or image

That's it. Works great for image popups. I wondered if I could add text content from an article. After analyzing the URL from the admin area I came up with a link that looks something like:

```
<a href="/index.php?option=com_name&id=##&tmpl=component&task=preview" class="modal"  rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 500, y: 400}}" >Text link here</a>
```

Substitute the Article ID for the ## characters.

[Read more](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1392625)

Controller

```
function preview()
{


        $view               = & $this->getView('viewname', 'html');  

        $view->setModel($model, true);
        $view->assignRef('data', $data); //whatever the data you want
        $view->display($tpl = null);


}
```